# The loaded '_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser' library is from a toolchain that is not compatible with this version of SwiftSyntax

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm using Xcode12.5 and swift version 5.4. When I try to build my project I get this error: The loaded '_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser' library is from a toolchain that is not compatible with this version of SwiftSyntax.

My Package.swift file:

import PackageDescription

```
let package = Package(
name: "NeedleFoundation",
products: [
    .library(name: "NeedleFoundation", targets: ["NeedleFoundation"]),
    .library(name: "NeedleFoundationTest", targets: ["NeedleFoundationTest"])
],
dependencies: [],
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "NeedleFoundation",
        dependencies: []),
    .testTarget(
        name: "NeedleFoundationTests",
        dependencies: ["NeedleFoundation"],
        exclude: []),
    .target(
        name: "NeedleFoundationTest",
        dependencies: ["NeedleFoundation"]),
    .testTarget(
        name: "NeedleFoundationTestTests",
        dependencies: ["NeedleFoundationTest"],
        exclude: []),
],
swiftLanguageVersions: [.v5]
```

)

```
#if compiler(>=5.4)
package.dependencies += [
    .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-format", .branch("swift-5.4-branch"))
]
#elseif compiler(>=5.3)
package.dependencies += [
    .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-format", .branch("swift-5.3-branch"))
]
#endif
```

And then I run : swift run swift-format
After that when I try to build my project I receive the same error:
The loaded '_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser' library is from a toolchain that is not compatible with this version of SwiftSyntax.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

From my research so far on this same problem, the issue is that whatever swift tool you are running (swift-format in this case) depends in the SwiftSyntax package and is not compatible with whatever version of Xcode (toolchain) you are using. You likely need to downgrade the version of Xcode you are using/the tool looks for. Still not sure what the best way to do that is though.